# How to get metadata of path from amazon s3 using aws v2?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

i am trying to get list of image names stored under specified path using amazon s3 v2 framework in ios. I don't know how to retrieve list of image names or metadata of path. In aws v1 framework, i had used object summaries option to retrieve the list of images under a path. So, how to get object summaries in AWS V2 ios framework?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AWSS3ListObjectsRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3ListObjectsRequest.html) has a property called [`prefix`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3ListObjectsRequest.html#//api/name/prefix). You can set the path to `prefix` and call [`- listObjects:`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3.html#//api/name/listObjects:) on [`AWSS3`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3.html).